# Troubles with data from Task thread

Tags: vb.net, task-parallel-library

I have a method where I collect variuous files for each of my products. I want to make that method async since it downloads files from other websites. ive made this code:

```
For Each product In productList
    If model.Sds Then
        Dim sdsTask As Task(Of ZipFile) = Task(Of ZipFile).Factory.StartNew(Function() GetSafetyDataSheets(product.Product))
        sdsTask.ContinueWith(Sub(t)
                                 product.SDS = t.Result
                                 Debug.WriteLine("test")
                             End Sub, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion)
        taskList.Add(sdsTask)
    End If
    If model.Apb Then
        Dim apbTask As Task(Of List(Of ZipFile)) = Task(Of List(Of ZipFile)).Factory.StartNew(Function() GetAPB(product.Product, model.Department))
        apbTask.ContinueWith(Sub(t) product.Instruction = t.Result)
        taskList.Add(apbTask)
    End If
    If model.Pdb Then
        Dim pdbTask As Task(Of ZipFile) = Task(Of ZipFile).Factory.StartNew(Function() GetProductDatasheet(product.Product))
        pdbTask.ContinueWith(Sub(t) product.PDB = t.Result)
        taskList.Add(pdbTask)
    End If


Next

Task.WaitAll(taskList.ToArray)
```

But when it has waited and im trying to access the SDS,APB or PDB in the products in my productslist, they are just empty object. I can see that my "getter" methods return just fine, but the data never makes it to the product.SDS property etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code tries to update a reference to a product that has changed. When the continuation runs, the instance pointed to by `product` is whatever value the external `product` variable has at that time. It could be the last product in the list, or any other product.

This is not a bug but the way external variable capture works with lambdas.

Instead of trying to access the external variable, pass its value to [TaskFactory.StartNew(Action(Of Object),Object)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321456.aspx) as a state value.

The same goes for the calls to ContinueWith. If you want to modify the product that was used in the previous step, you should pass it to the next step as part of the result, perhaps using a Tuple to do this.

Answer (score 1):

`ContinueWith` does not modify an existing task, but instead returns a new task that will complete when the continuation has completed. You're awaiting the original tasks (like `apbTask`), where you should be awaiting the results of the `ContinueWith` calls.